# how to get facebook post after a graph search?

Tags: facebook, post

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=xxxxxx&q=hello&type=post&fields=from,message,picture,link,name,caption,description,created_time&limit=1&locale=en_US&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,read_stream
```

After such a graph search, I get some data like:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "from": {
            "name": "Eric Fluegge",
            "id": "100000626293694"
         },
         "message": "Well, here's go nothing. Hello Tennessee.",
         "created_time": "2013-03-30T19:23:44+0000",
         "id": "100000626293694_567340783296793"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=from,message,picture,link,name,caption,description,created_time&q=hello&limit=1&type=post&locale=en_US&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&since=1364671424&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=from,message,picture,link,name,caption,description,created_time&q=hello&limit=1&type=post&locale=en_US&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&until=1364671423"
   }
}
```

so, is `"id": "100000626293694_567340783296793"` a post id? If so, how to use this post id, query again, get only this certain post information? I would like to store `post id` to mysql table, then I want to query the post anytime in the future, thanks.

**EIDT:** in app setting, i have set the `publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,read_stream`

**EIDT2:**
I have tried into `Graph API Explorer`, choose `read_stream` and generate a long live token.

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, type, attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id = "100000626293694_567340783296793"
```

the result still empty. so I cannot get a post bcause i am not a friend of the post auther? or `100000626293694_567340783296793` is not a post id? or other reason?

Comment: **offline_access** has been depreciated.

Comment: Indeed but it has been replaced with long-living access_tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, the `"id": "100000626293694_567340783296793"` is a post ID, you can query its data again with the following URL: `http://graph.facebook.com/100000626293694_567340783296793`

***Attention!***

You should ask for the **`read_stream`** permission/scope too! Or else you'll get the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
       "message": "Unsupported get request.",
       "type": "GraphMethodException",
       "code": 100
   }
}
```

And of course, append the access_token to your GET url. (and don't forget https too)

You can check the Graph API Reference here: [Post - Facebook Developer Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20actor_id%2C%20message%2C%20type%2C%20attachment%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20post_id%20%3D%20%22100000626293694_567340783296793%22, still nothing return. can you get the data in your test? i have set `read_stream` with a `long-living access_tokens`. thanks.

Comment: With your own token, you won't ever get access to that post. You must use your user's token if the post is not public.

Comment: @fishman did you try the search with the App Access token or User access token? I found a peculiar thing here, if you searched with user access token you get different result and the posts can be queried further. Have you tried this?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena That's what I was talking about. His own token he uses in the graph explorer won't work. You need a working test user.